# Find the limit of a natural logarithms product function

Tags: limits

How to find this limit:

$$\lim_{x\to\ 1}\ln x \ln (1-x)$$

I wanted to try L'Hôpital's rule, but it doesn't work here, cause i get:

$$\lim_{x\to\ 1} - \frac{\ln (x)}{1-x} + \frac{\ln (1-x)}{x}$$

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2191534

Comment: This is not well defined. You probably mean $\lim_{x\to\ 1^-}\ln x \ln (1-x)$.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/293025.